# What if a downvoter would risk a bit of his own reputation too?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I find questions of new contributors that get downvotes with no comments.
That's ok, when they are poorly formatted, the quality of the questions is of highest value for SO and the community.

But sometimes there are really good questions posted but they get downvoted for no reason (at least, no reason, I can see).

So, what if not only the people who ask questions (or answer them), but *also* those who downvote should take a second to think about the *quality* of their vote?

Long story short:
Say, person A downvotes a question, but 5 other people vote it up. So it is likely that A did not understand or read the question long enough to estimate the quality correctly.
This should lead also to a -x rep for the downvoter, as he clearly made a wrong decision.
If he removes his downvote, he gets the rep back of course.

It could be calculated with a formula like this: For every up-vote (count) above the number of downvotes you lose 1 rep.
So, a question with 2 downvotes and 3 upvotes gives -1 rep for each of the two downvoters. With every additional upvote, another -1.

Sometimes I think, downvoters could need a little discipline too, that's my oppinion.
I always think through the question (or answer) before voting it down (or up). But I don't think, everybody is doing this. There are many people rushing through questions and throwing out votes like "good...good...bad...bad...bad...good...ok done for now...10 minutes later...goood...bad...bad....bad...dont understand...bad..."
know what I mean?
/discuss

Comment: Without any special handling this would conflict with edits. Assume you downvote a really terrible post, then op edits it and it gets 10 upvotes. Why would you punish a downvoter for a vote that was justified for the initial state of the question?

Comment: ...and why should those downvotes stay alive when they no longer reflect the current state/quality of the question?
If the downvoter gets a red "-1" in the top right bar and he sees the question has been updated, he can... no he _should_ remove the no-longer-valid downvote!
It's a psychological thing. If you see a red number, it's like "oh maybe I did something wrong" - YES I think _removing_ no-longer-valid downvotes will _increase_ the quality.

Comment: using this logic, should someone lose reputation when they upvote a post that has a lot of downvotes?

Comment: Would this work the other way around? Upvoters losing rep if the question ends up at negative score or deleted? Would you be ok with this? Because it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes of course - I would be _very_ ok with this. friendship-colleague-upvotes and those are not a sign of quality. 
A voter shall _think about the quality of the vote_.
"Wrong" works in both directions, yes

Comment: @Grisgram Then could you update your question to not focus on downvotes? It doesn't make sense and I suspect it generates a lot of frustration here on meta as similar suggestions come in on a daily basis.

Comment: Another problem are votes on answers that are outdated. There is a large number of highly upvoted posts from the first years of SO that are now totally outdated and wrong. Giving a (e.g.) 500rep penalty now for downvoting content that was good at some point but is wrong now seems harsh.

Comment: I initially said yes to @Autar 's question, but when I think about it... No.
Why? The same psychological reason: If we create a positive community people are less scared to ask something.
Honestly, I had that already sometimes that I was too scared to ask something on SO, fearing senseless downvotes of people who don't take the time to read.
A down vote should be well thought and allow the originator to improve.
But _when_ the question gets updated, the votes shall be reconsidered too.
For many colleagues here at my work place, SO is a "100% read-only" site as no one wants to risk down's

Comment: And this leads to the worst possible scenario for SO: People stop asking questions as the punishment of downvotes comes so fast and so harsh - at least many feel bad when they ask something.

Just see this question... It went to -3 before even the first comment was posted. But I did nothing wrong - I just wanted to start a discussion... Why downvote something with (for a non-native) "ok" english grammar, that is no fun-post, not off-topic... Just a honest question. 
So... beloved downvoters of this question: WHY? How shall I know what you didn't like, if no one tells?

Comment: @Grisgram: On meta.SO votes are also used to indicate agreement or disagreement with your question. There is nothing wrong with your question, people just disagree with you.

Comment: About the other part of your last comments: SO should be used primarily as a read only resource. The overall goal is to be a repository of good questions and answers that help a large number of people. Asking should be the absolutely last resort when nothing else works. Whether it is really a worst case scenario when people are asking less on SO is questionable. Some might say that we have then accomplished the goal of having a knowledge base that covers all relevant topics.

Comment: Long story short: a skilled and experienced developer judges a question to be bad, and downvotes it.  The 30 other students, ring-voters, socks, whatever all upvote to punish the 'obviously elitist, bigoted, hostile' developer, who never answered another SO question again.

Comment: but @Grisgram, you are against "friend-colleagues" upvoting. But if I downvote a bad question and 5 "friend-colleagues" upvotes, I am now in the wrong and need to lose points? This makes *negative* sense. It may be an edge case, but it may happen. Then you'll detract people from downvoting, and you lose your best signal. Anyway, we shouldn't push downvotes away. What needs to happen is people need to not see downvotes as harsh or hostile. You got -3, with no comments, and you decided 'people hate this". No one gave you further feedback than the -3, which has a tooltip. It's psychological, 100%

Comment: @MartinJames So true. It's disappointing to see what gets voted up nowadays, by beginners who don't know better or by users perceiving downvotes as "unfriendly" and countervote for that reason.

Comment: It's also possible that one user downvoted when the question was in a bad state and upvotes occured after improvement - why punish the first voter for that?

Comment: @Modus *clearly* cause the voter is being irresponsible and doesn't sit for hours at the side of the new user to track any changes and edits to the post to correct their votes. Shame on the downvoter for not being able to give an hour of his time to someone who doesn't take time to phrase a good question (Is it clear enough I'm sarcastic?)

Comment: @Patrice It is :)

Comment: *"So, what if not only the people who ask questions (or answer them), but also those who downvote should take a second to think about the quality of their vote?"* ... I like the accusation that downvoters do not think before voting. Downvoters are bad persons anyway.

Comment: *But sometimes there are really good questions posted but they get downvoted for no reason* --> and what about really bad/trivial questions getting a lot of upvotes? they are more frequent ...

Comment: As always, if the suggestor has resistance to applying the same aspect to upvotes, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Fbueckert no no. it's ok to not follow the majority. As long as you are welcoming. If you follow the hostile majority, it's not okay. It's easy and clear to see, no? (oh gosh....)

Comment: If SO bowed to popularity, it would've gone the way of all the previous forums, @Patrice. :P

Comment: @fbueckert the majority doesn't seem to be with us on that :/ Will SO become just another Yahoo answers... and then in 5 years someone will go "we need a new Q&A format"? This feels like a bad joke, but I'm starting to feel it is the way we are headed :(

Comment: @Patrice I agree, but we're straying from the point with that.

Comment: "*For every up-vote (count) above the number of downvotes you lose 1 rep*" does that mean that if there are more downvotes than up, I'll **gain** rep by downvoting? :p

Comment: @Patrice You mean something like https://forum.codidact.org/

Answer (score 24):

> ...as they clearly made a wrong decision. If they remove their downvote, they get the rep back of course.

Voters (either up or down) don't make a decision let alone a wrong decision. The vote is mine and I indicate with my vote how useful I feel that content is. Don't go down the path that I somehow have to cater for how useful other users think a post is. That is a mind reading game without winners.

And if your idea nevertheless gets implemented then I predict we'll see less voting and not as early as it happens now. Users will wait for the first vote to come in and then either follow suit or refrain from voting. That is another stab to post quality on Stack Overflow. And like it or not, post quality is still the major benefit over other sites.

In the grand scheme of voting as a quality signal a couple of votes that don't follow the majority vote is not an issue, nor does it needs a correction on the behavior of the voter. Seeing a spread-vote should trigger others to pay more attention as there might be a yet to be discovered revelation that puts the content in a different light.

Vote early, vote often is still the best practice. I already risked my eyes and sanity over the content. That is enough risk for the voters. Leaving out the energy they have to spend on Meta to defend their stance.

Comment: I actually dread the idea of them implementing this and then retroactively [recalculating](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) it for all of time. That is a recipe for disaster and a great way to lose a lot of people's participation (I say that mostly for SE's benefit if they're reading, and the link is for future readers).